# Showing a sequence is short exact

Tags: modules, exact-sequence, unique-factorization-domains

Given a domain $R$ which is a UFD and $x,y \in R$ so that $\gcd(x,y)=1$, define $I = \left<x,y\right>$. I need to show that the sequence :

$$ 0 \rightarrow R \xrightarrow f R \oplus R \xrightarrow g I \rightarrow 0 $$

where $$f(a) = (-ya, xa)$$ and $$g(a,b) = ax+by$$

is exact.

I realise that basically means I need to show the surjectivity of $g$ and injectivity of $f$. But I am not sure why the UFD and relatively prime condition of $x$ and $y$ are thrown in. I am missing something elementary quite clearly, but I am unable to figure it out nevertheless. Any hints would be welcome.

Comment: You will need the "relatively prime" assumption in order to prove the other condition for the sequence to be exact: that the kernel of $g$ is equal to the image of $f$.  Injectivity of $f$ and surjectivity of $g$ do not require the "relatively prime" assumption, as you noticed.

Comment: Yeah..I see it now. Thanks.

Comment: Good, no problem.  May I encourage you to write an answer to your own question? It will get it out of the "unanswered" queue, and I'll vote it up.

Comment: @Pierre-GuyPlamondon , well I seem to be stuck again. Looks like my basics are rusty. I took an element in $(a,b) \in Ker(g)$, giving me $ax = -by$, which as $gcd(x,y)=1$ yields $x|b$ and $y|a$, but I am not able to move from here. Sorry, I guess was a bit too hasty in declaring it done.

Comment: What happens, say, if you write $a$ and $b$ as products of irreducible elements? Can you compare them?

Comment: I am not able to grasp your hint....sorry....I don't see how a and b can be compared, they might have some common prime(irreducible) factors or none, that's all

Comment: In general, that is true, but here you know that $ax=-by$...

Comment: well would it be right to say that x is one of the prime factors of b and y is one of a? so that would mean xy would be present on both sides

Comment: The right way to think about that is that $y$ is a non-zero divisor in $R/(x)$. If you use this, you can forget about everything else like co-prime and UFD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From $\gcd(x,y)=1$, we see that at least one of $x,y$ is non-zero. Hence the kernel of $f$ is trivial, as desired.

That $g$ is surjective is more or less the definition of $\langle x,y\rangle$.

We have $g\circ f=0$ because $g(f(a))=g(-ya,xa)=-yax+xay=0$ for all $a$.

Remains to show that $g(y,b)=0$ implies $(a,b)=f(c)$ for some $c$.
So assume $ax+by=0$, i.e., $ax=-by$. As $x$ is coprime to $y$, we must have $y\mid a$ and similarly $x\mid b$. So $a=dy$, $b=cx$ with $c,d\in R$. But then $dyx+cxy=0$ and so $d=-c$ and indeed $(a,b)=(-cy,cx)=f(c)$.